# Change WooCommerce shipping method label only on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I am trying to change the label of a radio button only on the checkout page, not the cart page.  The label is present on both pages.

When i enter the below code it changes the label on checkout page but makes the cart page blank.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'change_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
function change_shipping_label( $full_label, $method ){
    if( ! is_checkout()) return; // Only on checkout page?

    $full_label = str_replace( "Custom Carrier (Enter Details Next Page)", "Custom Carrier", $full_label );

    return $full_label;
}
```

---

[image: Checkout Page (correct label change]

[image: Cart Page (all labels have been wiped out]

Someone who knows why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually return nothing, because you only use `return;`. While it should be `return $label;`

- `is_checkout()` - Returns true on the checkout page.
- `str_replace` - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    // NOT returns true on the checkout page.
    if ( ! is_checkout() )
        return $label;

    $label = str_replace( "Custom Carrier (Enter Details Next Page)", "Custom Carrier", $label );

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 );
```